# iPhone Problem comparing course value for cllocation

Tags: iphone, compare, int, cllocationmanager

i'm writing some code for getting some values including course

```
    -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    //somecode
    NSString *dirString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", newLocation.course];
    int myInt = [dirString intValue];
    if ((myInt >= 0) || (myint  < 90)) {course.text =@ "N";}
    if ((myInt >= 90) || (myint  < 180)) {course.text =@ "E";}
```

and so on, but i always retrieve the first value, "N".

where's my mistake?

Thank's!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to change the logical OR to logical and (change `||` to `&&`) which will ensure that the value is between  0 and 90, or 90 and 180.

Because of the logical OR, the logic also seems a little flawed to me too, perhaps there is something I'm not understanding about the assumptions you've made - but if the value is, say, 200, it will pass the first `if` because 200 is greater than 0. It'll then also pass the second `if` because 200 is greater than 90. They pass because of the logical OR. Only one of the statements (>= 0 OR < 90) has to be true for it to pass.

This would be solved by using logical AND instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go via NSString to check the course, but the root cause of your bug is that the course is a double, you should use `%f` in the formating of your string.

shorter :

`double theCourse = newLocation.course;
if ((theCourse >= 0) || (theCourse  < 90)) {course.text =@ "N";}
if ((theCourse >= 90) || (theCourse  < 180)) {course.text =@ "E";}`

But actually I think your algo is wrong. You're going to the north if the course is 0<=course<45 or 315<=course<360 .

Comment: hi, i've try in your way and in another way:
    NSString *courseString = [[NSString alloc] 
    initWithFormat:@"%3.0f", newLocation.course];
    course.text = courseString;
In simulator i've try to assign a value to courseString and works.
On my device once get the value app crash and i've only mobile crash report (and i don't see nothing usefoul).
Any ideas? It's happened every time i do this with a double.

Comment: if you want 3 digits after the dot in your string, it's "%.3f"

Answer (score 0):

@yonel

thank's, course is in degree:-(
but i've not understand your algo, reading on apple doc i've found this:

```
Thus, north is 0 degrees, east is 90degrees, south is180 
degrees, and so on. Course values may not be available on all 
devices.
```

for me this mean

```
course between 0 and 44= North;
course between 45 and 89= NE; 
course between 90 and 134= East; 
course between 135 and 179= SouthEast;
course between 180 and 234= South;
course between 235 and 269= SouthWest;
course between 270 and 314= West;
course between 315 and 360 = NorthWest; -
```

Are we saying the same thing? :D